# SSRS Set parameter value based on another parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I know there are a handful of questions on this already, but I feel mine is a bit different.

I've built a report that is based on a date range that the user can specify using two date parameters (DateFrom, DateTo). However, I want a dropdown available that offers predefined date ranges, for example "Last 30 Days", "Last 60 Days", "Last 90 Days", "Last Month".

I've already created a dataset that generates these rows, example row would be:
Label = "Last30Days", DateFrom = 2016-08-15, DateTo = 2016-09-13

Basically, I want the usage flow as follows:
User loads the report, the Predefined date range parameter defaults to the Label "Manual" Value NULL. And the two date fields are empty. The user has the option to specify their own date range to whatever they want, or they can use the drop down and choose a pre-defined date range, which when selected, it populates the date parameters.

Is this easy to accomplish? I've used cascaded parameters before, but not really like this. I'm thinking more as I type this, and am wondering if I could just use some sort of expression....like, when an option in the drop down is selected, set the parameters to these values...?

EDIT:
So I was able to sort of get it working. I added available values (label/value match) to the preset dropdown for "Last [30|60|90] days", "Last month" and "manual". I set the default to "Manual". I added a parameter to the preset dates dataset and pointed it to the "PresetDates" parameter. Then I set the two date parameters to use the dataset for their default values. Now when you use the drop down, it populates the two date parameters just like I want...but if you try and select a different one once they've been populated, they don't change...

Comment: You can use Default values property of the date range parameters to populate your parameters by default using the drop down list. But if your user specify the dates the parameters will be populated with them. Let me know If you need further help.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I just finished trying that right when you commented. It "sort of works", see my edit in the OP. It populates the parameters with the values I want, but if you try changing the drop down, the values in the date parameters don't change.

Comment: what happen if the user populates the parameters and the dropdown is not set to **Manual**? Which would be the range, the specified in the dropdown or the specified in the date parameters?}

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Sorry if I don't understand your question. But the way it is set up right now is. the DateFrom/DateTo are what get passed into the sproc. So you can set the drop down to "Last90Days", it will populate the date parameters correctly, and then you can change the dates manually....when you run the report it will run based on whatever the user typed into the date parameters.

The only reason I have the "Manual" option is so the report doesn't automatically run when it opens. It starts out waiting for the user to enter dates, or for them to select a predefined date range.

Comment: I'd use two more parameters set as internal, then I'd add some logic to determine when should use the specified dates or the dropdown dates. If that sounds like a possible solution for you I'll answer with details.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta that's basically the route I ended up going with. I now have an internal parameter and a visible parameters for each DateFrom and DateTo. When the drop down is set to "Manual" it uses the visible parameters, when the drop down is anything else, it uses the hidden parameters. I will just have to explain to the users that in order to use the manual date, they have to set it to manual and uncheck the "NULL" checkboxes.

Comment: I'd use only the hidden parameters, populated based on the user selection. I don't understand why you use hidden in some cases and visible in others.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this won't work the way it should because of a <strike>BUG</strike> "feature" in SSRS.

Microsoft has **CLOSED** this <strike>BUG</strike> feature as <strike>We Hate Our Customers</strike> it **Works As Designed** (even though it's stupid).

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/268032/default-does-not-get-refreshed-for-cascading-parameters

Here's a possible answer but I don't think it would work in your case:

http://www.bp-msbi.com/2011/04/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/

Comment: Yup, I found that as I was researching other forums/sites. I did find a solution, but it required having two more VISIBLE parameters where their Available Values are equal to the data returned by the dataset filtered by the PresetDates parameter. And then the real DateFrom DateTo are set to those two new parameters....this works because when you change the drop down it now makes the DateFrom DateTo values invalid (not in the list of available values) and forces a parameter refresh....but I don't want to confuse the users with extra parameters that they don't use. lol.